# SPNEGO initialisation failing in the Spring boot based microservice

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, kerberos, websphere-liberty, spnego

In the project requirement, we need to develop a colleague authentication mechanism using SPNEGO(KERBEROS token) based configuration. we have successfully completed setup in the Liberty server for Keytab account, LDAP account, completed the required SPNEGO setup in the spring boot - microservice to enable SPNEGO SSO based authentication to access APIs. Liberty server configuration all looks good but seems like microservice is unable to initialise the SPNEGO security and SPNEGO SSO based authentication is failing due to some issue. seems like KERBEROS setup is not initialising, would appreciate if there is any working spring boot based microservice code sample available to refer which has required SPNEGO setup configuration and is working. Thank you.

Successfully completed setup in the Liberty server for Keytab account, LDAP account, completed the required SPNEGO setup in the spring boot - microservice to enable SPNEGO SSO based authentication to access APIs. Liberty server configuration all looks good but seems like microservice is unable to initialise the SPNEGO security and SPNEGO SSO based authentication is failing due to some issue. seems like KERBEROS setup is not initialising, would appreciate if there is any working spring boot based microservice code sample available to refer which has required SPNEGO setup configuration and is working. Thank you.

Comment: Enable SPNEGO related traces from this page and see what kind of error do you have - [MustGather: SPNEGO problems on WebSphere Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mustgather-spnego-problems-websphere-liberty)